# mercurial push /pull problem

Tags: mercurial

After my team friend did a push operation on our repo I can't do push operation.

First I commit later I click push

```
Push will not be performed because it would create remote branches.

You must first resync by doing a Pull from the target repository and Merge.
```

Later I click pull I got this

```
INFO Pulling From: https://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/itucs-blg361-2010-g27 ...
comparing with https://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/itucs-blg361-2010-g27
searching for changes
no changes found
INFO Pulled From: https://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/itucs-blg361-2010-g27
INFO To:        hastaneBilgiSistemi - C:\Users\yakUP\Desktop\wicket\hastaneBilgiSistemi
INFO: End of Mercurial Pull
```

What can I do?

I tried update. It says:

```
Mercurial Update
----------------
Update to revision 25 in:
C:\Users\yakUP\Desktop\wicket\hastaneBilgiSistemi
abort: crosses branches (use 'hg merge' to merge or use 'hg update -C' to discard changes)

INFO: End of Update
```

graph is like:
[image]
[image]Im new to mercurial.

Comment: It seems you already have multiple heads in your repository. That graph you link to, is that the one from the server, or from your local clone? Have you tried performing the merge like it suggests? If they're not supposed to be different branches, you should considering merging https://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/itucs-blg361-2010-g27/rev/e175c86d4a1e and https://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/itucs-blg361-2010-g27/rev/f1d6fd2e0e35, the two heads of your branches.

Comment: Also note that you have a case-folding collision between src/java/itucs/blg361/hbs/linkpage.java and src/java/itucs/blg361/hbs/linkPage.java (note upper-case P in linkPage in one of the two, and lower-case in the other). This prevents updating to the tipmost changeset on a Windows-system.

Comment: you are right but i dont know how to merge the two versions.

Comment: and i tried the fix the collision but couldn't do it

Comment: To prevent such case folding problems in the future, download and install this Mercurial extension: http://hackd.net/projects/caseguard/

Comment: You can find the files for caseguard here: http://bitbucket.org/alexandru/caseguard/src - although I'm not entirely sure it will work with Mercurial 1.7. It's 8 months old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the message about creating new heads on the server, yet pull saying there is no new changesets, means that you already have all the changesets from the server.

What you should do is look in your local clone and merge the multiple heads together to get one again, then you should be able to push.

However, you probably won't be able to do this on Windows (judging by the path examples in your question) since there is a case-folding collision between two files:

- src/java/itucs/blg361/hbs/linkpage.java <-- notice lower-case p in linkPage
- src/java/itucs/blg361/hbs/linkPage.java <-- notice upper-case P in linkPage

This will prevent you from actually using that branch unless someone with a system that considers the two to be different files (like *nix) gets rid of one of them for you, pushing that, and then you pulling in that new changeset.

So you have a couple of options:

- Force the push with --override (or the GUI equivalent). This is usually not the right way. This will create another head on the server, and then suddenly you have at least 3 different versions of the project.
- Pull (like you've done), merge, then push. This is usually the preferred choice. You should merge together the heads that belong together to get back to one branch.

In any case, I would figure out why you have multiple heads in the repository already. Did someone force a push? Was it intentional?

**And get [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) - It'll make your life easier**

Comment: i did force push.Because i can't do any operation on repo how can i fix this? can you write the code

Comment: No, you need to merge. I can't do that for you since I'm on Windows, and as I said, there's a case-folding problem in your repository. You've managed to add two files (linkpage.java and linkPage.java) in the same directory with only an uppercase/lowercase character as the difference. This isn't supported on Windows, which means that part of the branch is unavailable. Otherwise I'd attempt a merge for you, but I can't even look at that branch.

Comment: how can i fix case folding collision

Comment: Well, there are possibly some extensions that can help although I don't know their names. The `fold` extension doesn't work with Mercurial 1.7 apparently. You could always strip away the offending changesets, but you'd loose all the changes from it and descendant changesets (3-4 of the tipmost ones.) so you'd have to reimplement that. Or you could get someone with a Linux system to try to help you out.

Comment: So then you need to resolve those. To be blunt, using a DVCS that relies heavily on branching on merging, it is *imperative* that you learn and understand merging enough to use it. Otherwise you should move to a centralized source control system like Subversion.